# Using Script edit the file and replace some variable value

Tags: linux, command, vi

I have n number of servers like:

```
c0001234.cloud.com
c0005678.cloud.com
c0009123.cloud.com
```

I need to write one script that will login to these servers and edit one file. Basically there is one variable in that file and I have to replace that value.
Successfully able to login to the servers but but able to edit the file.
How can I write the script that will edit the file on all the servers.
FileName and Variable name is same on all the servers.

```
string2=c0001234.cloud.com,c0005678.cloud.com,c0009123.cloud.com
for j in $(echo $string2 | sed "s/,/ /g")
do
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt -q AppAccount}@$j stty < /dev/null
    ????????????????????????
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of `stty < /dev/null`?

First, don't use comma as separator, use space, it simplifies the loop later.

```
string2="c0001234.cloud.com c0005678.cloud.com c0009123.cloud.com"
for j in $string2; do
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no AppAccount@$j sed -i -e 's/var/value/g' file
done
```

This will replace `var` with `value` in `file`.